# Trouble updating a <div> after successful validation using jQuery Validation plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a form using the [jQuery Validation plug-in](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), and I'm having some trouble updating a `<div>` with the status once the form is submitted (called using `submitHandler`). Once the user clicks to submit the form, it should update the `#inviteStatus` element with a status ("Adding user"). Then, once the response is received from the server (1-2 seconds) it should update `#inviteStatus` again with a result ("Success" or "Fail"). However, my script is jumping directly to the latter update ("Success" or "Fail"), and skipping the first "Adding user" update.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhall7x/Mf7sq/4/

I tried inserting a `delay(5000);` after the first `<div>` update, but the script seems to just stop at that point, and never continues on to the second result update message.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I've created an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhall7x/Lh942/1/) that has the actual code that I'm using. I can't get the `.ajax()` query to actually work on JS Fiddle, but this way you can see what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, I'd like to first update `#inviteStatus`, show it, then 
update it with the results of my `.ajax()` query. Here's the code I'm using in the `submitHandler` of the jQuery Validation plug-in after the form is successfully validated:

```
// form successfully validated, provide user notification
$("#inviteStatus").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\">Adding user</div>");
$("#inviteStatus").show(500);

// get form values
var postData = $(form).serializeArray();

// submit form
$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    data        : postData,
    async       : false,
    cache       : false,
    url         : "inviteScript.php",
    success: function(result) {
        // Provide the results of the ajax call
        $("#friendInviteStatus").html(result);
        $("#friendInviteStatus").show(500).delay(5000).hide(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: I was actually able to get this to work by disabling the `async:false` in the `.ajax()` settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get this to work by removing the `async:false` on the `.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine, to simulate the ajax you need to give a delay

```
// Form actions
$("#addForm").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        invitee: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        invitee: "Please enter a username"
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $("#inviteStatus").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\">Adding user</div>");
        $("#inviteStatus").show(500);

        // submit form here via ajax() call
        //simulate the ajx call
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#inviteStatus").html("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Success!</div>");
            $("#inviteStatus").show(500).delay(5000).hide(500);
        }, 2000)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9jLb5/)

---

Another slightly modified version is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9jLb5/2/ - It is not recommended since it delays sending the ajax request till the message is completely shown

Comment: Thanks Arun. I've created an updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bhall7x/Lh942/1/ that shows the actual code I'm using. I can't get the `.ajax()` call to work in JS Fiddle, but at least this way you get the point of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an anonymous function to the `show()` call instead of altering the `html` on a different line.

```
$("#inviteStatus").show(500);
// submit form here via ajax() call
$("#inviteStatus").html("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Success!</div>");
```

Should be

```
$("#inviteStatus").show(500,function() {
    // submit form here via ajax() call
    $("#inviteStatus").html("<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Success!</div>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mf7sq/7/

Comment: Thanks! Would you still recommend this approach given my edits above which contains the second `html` update in the `success:` handler of the `.ajax()` call?